# A running process is never being found

Tags: c#, soap, process

I am working on a c#/soap/php project where the php web interface will do a soap request to determine if the console application is running.

The soap request calls a function that gets the processes and then loops through to determine if the process name contains `EmailServer`. However, this is never being found even though I can see the process `EmailServer.exe` in Task Manager. I've also put a breakpoint so I can look through what processes is in the array and EmailServer is not there.

I'm running Windows 7 x64 with .net framework 3.5 and I am logged in as Administrator account so it can't be a permissions problem.

Below is a screenshot which shows my process running in Task Manager [image]

Below is the code that gets the process list

```
public bool checkIfProcessIsRunning()
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process process in processes)
            {
                if (process.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("EmailServer"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> process.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("EmailServer")

You're checking if an all lowercase string contains a string with uppercase characters.

Comment: So you want `process.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("emailserver")` - or alternately (if you want case-sensitivity) `process.ProcessName.Contains("EmailServer")`

Comment: Thanks you were right, I also as well as a second problem I was returning false within the foreach so it would ever check the first process in the list, I think that I must be having a bad day to notice. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead: `process.ProcessName.IndexOf("EmailServer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1`

You can also use

```
if(Process.GetProcessesByName("EmailServer").Count() > 0)
```

or simply

```
public bool checkIfProcessIsRunning(){
    return Process.GetProcessesByName("EmailServer").Any();
}
```

Comment: Going to be nitpicky here and point out that you should use a property rather than a method here; you're returning information, not doing an operation. Also, a "better" name would be IsProcessRunning or something similar, as long as it complies with the naming conventions.